# Dihedral group definition

Tags: abstract-algebra

What does the following mean in the context of dihedral groups?

$D_n$ is generated by a rotation $r$ of order $n$ and a reflection $s$ of order 2 such that $srs = r^{-1}$.

This is taken from wikipedia. Can anyone explain this in the context of triangle, $n=3$?

Comment: You have asked several questions on dihedral groups within the last hours. I want to point out K. Conrad's excellent [notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/dihedral.pdf) on dihedral groups. This should help you with all of the questions.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in terms of an equilateral triangle with vertices $1,2,3$, the rotations are $id=(1)(2)(3)$,  $r =(1,2,3)$ and $r^2 =(1,3,2)$, and the reflections are $s_1=(1)(2,3)$, $s_2=(2)(1,3)$ and $s_3=(3)(1,2)$.
The dihedral group $D_3$ equals the symmetric group $S_3$.

Answer (score 1):

Abstractly, "The dihedral group is generated by $r$ and $s$" means that all elements of $D_3$ may be represented by a word using the letters $r,s,r^{-1}$ and $s^{-1}$, with group operation given by putting one word after the other. In any word, we may cancel $r$ and $r^{-1}$ if they are next to one another, and we may cancel $s$ and $s^{-1}$ if they are next to one another, without changing which element the word represents.

The fact that $s$ is of order $2$ means that $ss$ is the identity and may be removed from any word without changing the element. As a consequence, $s$ and $s^{-1}$ are the same, and all $s^{-1}$ may be exchanged with $s$. The fact that $r$ is of order $3$ means that $rrr$ is the identity and may be removed from any word without changing the element. As a consequence $r^{-1}$ is the same as $rr$, and all $r^{-1}$ may be exchanged with $rr$.

Thus any element of $D_3$ may be represented using words with the symbols $r$ and $s$, where neither $rrr$ nor $ss$ appear .

Finally, the last property says that $srs=r^{-1}$. A small rewriting gives us $sr=rrs$. Which is to say that if you ever have an $s$ immediately to the left of an $r$ in a word, you may swap them around, provided you turn the $r$ into $rr$ in the process. This does not change which element the word represents.

The end result is that any element may be represented by a word using only $r$ and $s$, where all the $r$'s are on the left and all the $s$'s are on the right, and where there are at most $2$ $r$'s next to one another, and at most one $s$. So all elements of $D_3$ are represented by the six words
$$
e,r,rr,\\
s,rs,rrs
$$
where "$e$" means the empty word; the word with no symbols in it.

I know and you know that we are done now, but showing that these words all represent distinct elements (in other words, *proving* that we are done now) can be difficult, at least in general. In this specific case, if we assume that two of these words represent the same element, we quite quickly contradict the assumption that $s$ has order $2$ or $r$ has order $3$.